# write at once a second using bufferedwriter on android

Tags: java, android, android-sensors, bufferedwriter

I want to write gyro sensor values to file on sdcard.
I prefer to use bufferedwriter but cant use it periodically. how it does?

Comment: Use timertask to set periods

Comment: timertask needs a final values(string, float...), but gyroscope sensor returns float continuously, so it doesnt

Comment: Try to use Thread.sleep(1000) after you have read the values and than read again. Maybe you have to redesign your I/O Thread for this. Its not nice but if you cant use Timers it could help.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of ways to do this. But let's start with looking at some of your relevant code. Post the code so we understand your structure and we can help from there. Rest assured this problem is very trivial and I'm sure you'll get a working response shortly thereafter.